# Paperclip ignores image sizing options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, paperclip

So I've got the Paperclip gem setup in my project to handle cover images for a model called `Story`:

```
class Story < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
    has_attached_file :cover_image,
                      styles: { large: "700x700>", thumb: "300x300>" },
                      default_url: "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/default_image.jpg",
                      path:"/cover_images/:filename",
                      processors: [:thumbnail, :paperclip_optimizer]
```

I'm trying to use the `thumb` style for when the story is displayed in a small format, which looks like this:

```
<div class="image">
    <%= image_tag story.cover_image.url(:thumb) %>
</div>
```

[image: Small Image Format]

This is the way the [Paperclip documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Thumbnail-Generation) says you should specify which style you want to use.

In this context, the image has the correct dimensions of 300x111px.

However, when I move to my story page, I want the large/full size version of the image:

```
<div class="header_image">
    <%= image_tag(@story.cover_image.url(:large)) %>
```

Except paperclip incorrectly still uses the thumbnail version of the image:

[image: Incorrect sizing]

[image: Low Resolution]

Why isn't Paperclip sizing the images correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You must specify a `:style` option in the `path`:

```
has_attached_file :cover_image,
                      styles: { large: "700x700>", thumb: "300x300>" },
                      default_url: "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/default_image.jpg",
                      path:"/cover_images/:filename/:style",
                      processors: [:thumbnail, :paperclip_optimizer]
```

Now Paperclip will upload different versions of the image and access them as needed:

[image: Style options]

[image: Large image being used]